# Is there a way to "undercommit" memory in Linux (VPS burst memory woes)?

Tags: linux, memory, performance, vps, hypervisor

I've been noticing occasional *drastic* performance hiccups in my application hosted on a VPS. My VPS plan has 1GB guaranteed RAM and 1GB "burst" RAM. Occasionally the app will become extremely sluggish, then suddenly it will become responsive again. After some investigation I've determined that the hiccups seem to occur when I'm above my guaranteed 1GB of RAM even when I'm well below my 2GB total. There don't seem to be any other patterns (CPU and disk activity all look normal during the hiccups).

My guess is that my 1GB of "burst" RAM the hypervisor is giving me is actually going out to a spinning disk during these slow times... So it's really like I'm running with a 1GB swap disk but (here's the key) Linux doesn't **know** that it really only has 1GB RAM + 1GB "swap".

I have a hunch that all the fine-tuned algorithms in the kernel memory management subsystem are being completely thrown off by the fact that the system is reporting 2GB of usable RAM when there's really only 1GB.

It seems like most of the knobs I can fiddle with are targeted at configuring the system to use *more* RAM than it really has. Is there a way to go in the opposite direction (i.e. become more conservative when we start approaching 1GB of used memory)?